# jssor caption text cut on caption transition

Tags: text, jssor, caption

I have a problem that I can't solve.

I have a caption with text and I want to apply a dashed border around it. I use css to make all the styling, but when the slider starts after some loops the caption transitions that applied to the text, cause a strange cut arround the border and the text. The size of the div (width and height) is correct. I will post the css and the html below.

CSS class:

```
.items {
    overflow:visible !important;
    z-index:111 !important; 
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 215px;
    height: 46px;
    top: 296px;
    left: 152px;
    text-align: left;
    font-family: Roboto-Bold, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color: #0b67ad;
    font-size: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    line-height: 24px;
    border:2px dashed #fff;
    border-radius:10px;
    -webkit-border-radius:10px;
    -moz-border-radius:10px;
    }
```

and the HTML for the div:

```
 <div  u=caption t="*" class="items">sample text</div>
```

I have done a lot of changes in this code in order to find what cause this behavior but nothing worked.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What's the browser with problem?

Comment: It seems there is no problem at my end. Please post full code (html+javascript) if possible.

Comment: I have managed to solve the problem by changing the caption effects. It seems that some conflict happened with the others. By the way all the browsers had the same issue (Google Chrome, IE, Mozilla Firefox).